# Remove Duplicates in Power Query WITHOUT Removing Entire Row

Tags: excel, duplicates, powerquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BvPR.png)I need to remove duplicates in multiple columns without removing the entire row. I have a Query with multiple columns and there are 6 columns I want to remove duplicates from. The column headers are:

"Unforcasted Orders"
"Forecasted Orders"
"Forecasted and Unforcasted"
"Open Orders"
"Capability"
"Actuals"

My previous applied step is "Reordered Columns2".
What is the M code for this? Thanks in advance.

I cannot group by because each "Forecast Date" is for a given month and with that month it corresponds to multiple months as "Month in Forecast". If I cannot remove these duplicates without removing the entire row, is there a way to replace the duplicates with null or make them blank? Thanks.

Comment: Please post sample before and after data. In tabular data, it's not possible to "not remove an entire row".

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I will attach a photo

Comment: So it doesn't matter what the the values are in the Product, Forecast Date, Month in Forecast or Attribute columns ? We should ignore those columns completely and remove duplicates from the specified columns ?  Or are we only removing duplicates based on groupings of the other columns?

Comment: @horseyride you are correct, the values in Product, Forecast Date, Month in Forecast or Attribute columns doesn't matter because there are duplicates and I want those duplicates to remain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all duplicates in specified columns no matter what the values are in the remaining [Product, Forecast Date, Month in Forecast, Attribute] columns then use

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Reordered Columns2", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Index",{"Product", "Forecast Date", "Month in Forecast", "Attribute", "Index"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Index"}, "Attribute.1", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Index",{"Product", "Forecast Date", "Month in Forecast", "Attribute"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns2" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Index"}, "Attribute.1", "Value"),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns2", {"Attribute.1", "Value"}),
Combined = #"Unpivoted Other Columns" & #"Removed Duplicates",
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Combined, List.Distinct(Combined[Attribute.1]), "Attribute.1", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Forecast Date", type date}, {"Month in Forecast", type date}})
in #"Changed Type1"
```

If you want to remove all duplicates in specified columns based on first grouping together by [Product, Forecast Date, Month in Forecast, Attribute], then use

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Reordered Columns2", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Product", "Forecast Date", "Month in Forecast", "Attribute","Index"}, "Attribute.1", "Value"),
#"Removed Duplicates1" = Table.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Product", "Forecast Date", "Month in Forecast", "Attribute", "Attribute.1", "Value"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Duplicates1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Duplicates1"[Attribute.1]), "Attribute.1", "Value", List.Sum),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Hi @horseyride thank you for your response. I tried the second option you shared with me because I am trying to remove all duplicates in specified columns based on first grouping together by (Product, Forecast Date, Month in Forecast, Attribute) although it didn't accomplish the output I am trying to achieve. When I add an index column I am able to see that my data doesn't contain any multiple indexes. So maybe this means there isn't any true duplicates? If this is the case, is there a way to replace duplicates with null or 0 rather than removing duplicates? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If there is no duplicates how would you replace them?